# My mom offered to share her iPhone Health app data with me. Do I have to put MY data in iCloud to see HER data?

Tags: iphone, icloud, privacy, health.app

My phone says: "**Health in iCloud is Turned Off** The Health app uses iCloud to access health data that is shared with you. To receive invitations to share and view data, turn on Health in iCloud."

I don't want my Health data in iCloud, and I know that if I ever sync my data with iCloud the only way to revoke iCloud's access is to destroy the data so that it is irrevocably destroyed.

Is there any way to see my mom's data without compromising my data?

Answer (score 2):

Health sharing operates through the same process that Health in iCloud operates, so yes you have to turn on Health in iCloud to see shared Health records.

If you have a secondary device, you could enable it on just that device to see the records, but this is obviously less than ideal.

You can always revoke the data in iCloud without deleting it from your device. If you turn off Health in iCloud you can then delete the data stored in iCloud and leave your data untouched on your device locally.

Lastly, if this changes your decision, Health data is one of the few iCloud sync items that are properly End-to-End encrypted. If you lose access to your devices you cannot recover your Health data. This is different than your photos, emails, and iCloud backups, which can be recovered if you regain access to your account.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/back-up-your-health-data-iph11f1eb698/ios

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way to see my mom's data without compromising my data?

#### The short answer is YES...but....

However, there are details you should be aware of regarding the Health Sharing feature.

Now, I am in a position to reciprocate, therefore I've come here to help communicate why exactly does require (encourage the proverbial "you" to setup your data.

### How is my data secured

There is a limitation of the data per topic that you can share, but you can get info in the case of updated info. For example....

- You can watch yourself,  up to 5 people.

#### Choose your favorite categories to track

- On your iPhone or iPad, open the Health app.
- If you're on your iPhone, tap the Summary tab. If you're on your iPad, tap
- Categories with a "blue star" is designated a favorite so any data will be printed on my iOS device. To remove the favorites tag,

If you're on your iPhone, tap the Summary tab. If you're on your iPad, tap  to open the sidebar, then tap Summary which will bring you to the correct

Tap Edit next to Favorites.
To add or remove a category from your favorites, tap it. Categories with a blue star  appear in your favorites.

You can even request sharing with someone.  The Mac and the device[s].  All info is backed up to an "area" outside of iCloud. This reserved partition was created and encrypted by Apple - I doubt they want to share.

#### Erasing shared data.

The Health app communicates using an encrypted connection. See this excellent Technical Document as provided for by Apple.

Share and view health data in the Health app via the step-by-step instructions provided by Apple.

#### TL;DR

1. Can you share Helth App Data, YES.  You can even *request* someone share their health data
2. Is there any limitations?  YES.

   For direct connections, you're limited to 5 people. To modify any data including account data for a watched entity.  Which brings us  to...

What is available to monitor (rethorical and "monitor = pay attention to")?  Well, that's ultimately to the dev.  It makes sense there are some categories like blood pressure automatically included

2. To modify or remove ite ms from the Health App Database, it requires unencrypting (and re-encrypting) the file which destroys all data within the container.